# How to set and save string in TextView?

Tags: android

I have a TextView where there is some text. Below is EditText, which changes the TextView field by pressing Button. When I go back to the previous card and go back to the card where I changed the text, the previously changed text was not saved. I would like the changed text in the TextView to be there permanently until the next edit.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_url);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    devices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buildings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.devices);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buildings);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String niu = ed1.getText().toString();
            devices.setText(niu);


        }
    });

}
```

I've seen a lot of posts using SharedPreferences and onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState, but I do not know how to properly use them. Can someone make my code to get the result described at the beginning? I've been sitting on it for a long time and have no effect

After answers I edit my code like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_url);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    devices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buildings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.devices);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buildings);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String niu = ed1.getText().toString();
            devices.setText(niu);


        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            String niu2 = ed2.getText().toString();
            devices.setText(niu2);
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("TEXT", (String) devices.getText());
    outState.putString("TEXT2", (String) buildings.getText());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    devices.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT"));
    buildings.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT2"));

}
```

It doesnt work why?

Comment: No body will do code for you. you have to learn from reference.

Comment: "When I go back to the previous card and go back to the card where I changed the text" What do you mean by this? Do you mean that you have two activities?

Comment: Yes, I meant two activities

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an [mcve].  It seems to me that the code you show here has an extra button, textview,  and edittext  that are not important to your question. You are also missing `class ??? extends ???`.

Comment: Just the rest of the components will work on the same basis as the first. Because in one activity there will be two TextView to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you must either use shared preferences or store values in global variables. Make sure you have a proper grip of android [activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Using SharedPreferences:

```
public void saveStringInSharedPreferences(String text) {
    // Retrieve the default shared preferences instance available to full application
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("KEY", "VALUE").commit();
}
```

Retrieving the saved value:

```
sharedPreferences.getString("KEY", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

Using onSaveInstanceState: (This is not what you must use for above requirement)

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("TEXT", (String) textView.getText());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    textView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT"));
}
```

But before using onSaveInstanceState read this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is called only when activity is killed forcefully by the operating system for some reasons, it will not be called when pressed back or when activity is not killed forcefully by OS.